# Frame overview in top bar

Tags: frames

I'm using emacs in a text terminal and would like to have an overview over the frames at all times. Something like the tab bar in firefox would be neat. Is that possible somehow?

Comment: What do you want out of an overview? A list of all open buffers? The status bar at the top of the screen? Something else?

Comment: not a list of all buffers but a list of all frames. Preferably in a status bar at the top of the screen

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure what the use case is, but something like the following creates a selectable "tab bar" of frames in the header line.:

```
(require 'cl-lib)
(setq-default header-line-format
      '((:eval
         (let ((frames (frame-list)))
           (mapconcat 
            'identity
            (cl-loop for frame in frames
                     as map = (make-sparse-keymap)
                     do (define-key
                          map
                          [header-line mouse-1]
                          `(lambda () (interactive) (select-frame-set-input-focus ,frame)))
                     if (eq frame (selected-frame))
                     collect (propertize
                              (frame-parameter frame 'name)
                              'face '(:foreground "#B8bb26")
                              'keymap map)
                     else collect (propertize
                                   (frame-parameter frame 'name)
                                   'face '(:foreground "#FB4933")
                                   'keymap map))
            " | ")))))
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me. It only shows an empty black line on the top of each buffer. Even if I comment out all other customizations. The use-case is to keep the overview over open frames in the same way as e.g. `byobu` does (e.g. on this image on the bottom https://i.ytimg.com/vi/rVMn3xk5mcY/maxresdefault.jpg).

Comment: @Jonas, I suspect that if you change `(string-join` to `(mapconcat 'identity` it will stop being empty.

Comment: @phils darn, you're probably right. I should get used to knowing which functions are in `subr-x` and which have backward compatibility.